# Retrieve ipa file from worklight proejct

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Does anyone know how to get the .ipa file for my iPhone environment within IBM worklight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Inside your iPad environment -> native folder you can find the xCode project file named `YourAppNameipad.xcodeproj`. Open the file will open the xCode with your current project.
- Else right Click your app folder RunAs -> Run As xCode project will open the project in xCode.

After that you can follow the normal procedure to build the IPA.

- Select iOS device
- Product -> Archive

Answer (score 0):

[Please read the training materials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) IBM provides.

Worklight Studio, the Eclipse plug-in, **does not** generate the .ipa file for you.
Only Xcode does that, and so in order to "get" the .ipa, you need to actually Build the Xcode project that Worklight Studio generates, in Xcode.

[Read here how to get the .ipa file from Xcode](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=xcode%20how%20to%20get%20the%20ipa&oq=xcode%20how%20to%20get%20the%20ipa&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i65j69i59.2295j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8).